# is it logical to create ordering service in one node in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I created a Hyperledger Fabric network (not sample-network or test-network). I have 4 nodes. One ordering service (4 orderers) in one node. In production that node is crashed, what will happen. Does the raft algorithm will same the data, when it is shut down? If I create 2 and 2 orderers in 2 separated nodes, then I can't define to different ordering service when I create a channel. If I do, it gets really complicated.

Is there any solution or clean explanation for it.

I am a full time learner, If you want to give -1. Then you owe me a solution also.

Answer (score 0):

The raft algorithm is used by the ordering service nodes in a Hyperledger Fabric network to maintain consensus and ensure data integrity. In the event of a node failure, the remaining nodes will continue to operate and maintain the ledger state.

If you have a single node with multiple orderers, and that node crashes, the ordering service will be unavailable until the node is restored. This can cause disruption to the network and may affect transaction processing.

If you want to increase the resilience of your network, you can set up multiple ordering service nodes and distribute the orderers across those nodes. This way, if one node goes down, the remaining nodes can still provide the ordering service and maintain the integrity of the network.

To define multiple ordering services when creating a channel, you can specify the orderer addresses in the channel configuration file. For example, if you have two ordering service nodes with the following orderer addresses:

```
node1-orderer1: orderer.example.com:7050
node1-orderer2: orderer.example.com:7051
node2-orderer1: orderer2.example.com:7050
node2-orderer2: orderer2.example.com:7051
```

You can add them to the channel configuration file like this:

```
"orderers": [
    "orderer.example.com:7050",
    "orderer.example.com:7051",
    "orderer2.example.com:7050",
    "orderer2.example.com:7051"
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When You create channel ../../bin/peer channel create -o localhost:7050  this command. It wants sinle ordering service node. How can I give multiple IP address.

Comment: When creating a channel in Hyperledger Fabric using the peer channel create command, you can specify multiple ordering service nodes by providing a comma-separated list of their addresses.

Comment: where I will add these orderers in channel configuration file I have just one simple missing knowledger. Do ı need to add inside under Profiles section inside configtx.yaml file  or under Orderer: &OrdererDefaults